# Firebase keys issue with POJO with ArrayList of POJO

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a POJO object which contains an ArrayList of another POJO (friends).. While storing data with

```
Map<String, Object> map = new ObjectMapper().convertValue(pojoObject, Map.class);
```

When added with firebase `updateChildren`, keys of ArrayList becomes 0,1,2,3 ..

What I see is this:

[image]

Is there any way I can have random ids (push ids) for ArrayList Objects inside Main Object instead of 0,1,2,3 etc ?

Comment: Do you know having an object in another object is a bad design when using Firebase?

Comment: `DatabaseReference.push()` is the method you're probably looking for. Maybe search around before asking a question.

Comment: @RohitNavarathna, I know what push() method does, Generating key from the push for my main Object, but for the ArrayList inside the Object automatically generates ids like, 0,1,2,3.. That is the problem ..

Comment: ah.. my bad. I don't know any way other than iterating through the ArrayList